# Cross domain behavior in WCF service hosted in .exe process

Tags: jquery, wcf

Recently I was involved in WCF creation and I have encountered cross domain issue when I was trying to consume it, by sending data from $.ajax function.

```
  var dto = { };
  dto.Id = 1;
  dto.Name = "Test";

  var DTO = { 'jsonMesssage': dto };

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "http://localhost/JsonService/ProcessMessage",
      data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
      dataType: "json",
      crossDomain:true,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result.d);
      },
      error: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(a, b, c);
      }
```

I found the way how people solved it for those WCF services that were hosted on IIS, but I have other situation because WCF is hosted inside of .exe process

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

but how to accomplish the same, lets say  interceptor being able to correctly fix cross domain issue?

Comment: I have the same problem... have you found any solution ?